# How do i parse a text between two tags?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string long string with some tags inside:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);

string page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
w.Write(page);
w.Close();
```

I want to get from the page variable or either the html file all the text between the two tags:

```
<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=81020&forum=scoops1"><b>test</b>
```

I want to parse the word test. So in the end i will have all the words between:

```
<a href="http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=81020&forum=scoops1"><b>
```

and `</b>`

EDIT**

This is in the constructor how i saving the html file:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
string page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");
w.Write(page);
w.Close();
ExtractText(@"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html");

private void ExtractText(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the text List i dont see hebrew but gibberish.
The html file on my hard disk i see inside hebrew fonts since i encoded it in the constructor.
But in the text List i see it in gibberish again.

Comment: [Use the library... Luke](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an HTML parsing library such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which would allow you to easily locate the information you are looking for inside the markup:

```
string filePath = @"d:\rotterhtml\rotterscoops.html"

var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

In this example I have selected the value of all `<b>` tags nested inside an `<a>` tag. You might need to adapt the selector to match your needs:

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
```

Comment: How can i encode it to hebrew fonts ? The text im trying to parse is in hebrew. The html file on my hard disk i see the hebrew fonts but when i parse it with the htmlagilitypack i dont see hebrew but ×”×ž×§×‘×™×œ×” ×œ ''×™×”×•×“×•×Ÿ'' ××• ''× ×™×’×¨'' ×”×•×¤×š ×œ×§×œ×œ×” ×”×›×™ ×¤×•×¤×•×œ×¨×™×ª ×‘××¨×”''×

Comment: Updated my question showing how im encoding it in the cosntructor and after using the htmlagilitypack its in gibberish again.